# Append to the second to last li

Tags: jquery

Ok so I have this `HTML` structure and I need to keep appending a new `li` after test3 and so on...right before the form `li`. I know how to do the append logic in `jquery` but how do I isolate and make sure I can keep doing it....maybe use the live function.

```
<td class="resources_present">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://test.com">http://test.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://test2.com">http://test2.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://tes3.com">http://test3.com</a></li>
<li><form method="post" id="new_resource" class="new_resource" action="/resources" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: inline;"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="BEeMlTtPiMi8mv/whQ2z757CTTOnNl0oiPpN3WdqSBg=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" size="30" name="resource[url]" id="resource_url">
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="resource[course_id]" id="resource_course_id">
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" name="commit" id="resource_submit" style="display: inline;">
        <img class="noShow" src="/images/spinner.gif" style="display: none;">
  </div>
</form></li>
</ul>
</td>
```

Basically I need to find the selector to add this:

```
    <li><a href="http://test4.com">http://test4.com</a></li> // after the 

            <li><a href="http://test3.com">http://test3.com</a></li> // and continue to do that with 5, 6 , 7, and so on
```

Answer (score 15):

Many ways to do this. Here's one:

```
$('li:last').prev();
```

And to add:

```
$('li:last').prev().after('<li><a href="http://test4.com">http://test4.com</a></li>');
```

Comment: In well-formed HTML the prev element of an li should be an li, no? (unless the list only has 1 element, which is not the example HTML)

Answer (score 7):

`$("#yourselectorid li").eq(-2)` should do the trick

**EDIT**

Assuming you have at least 2 `<LI>` already present (one being the form)

Comment: Cool didn't know it's possible to use negative values like that with eq()

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.after()` function for this.

Give your test3 a class or id to find it easily like this:

```
<li id="insertafter"><a href="http://test3.com">http://test3.com</a></li>
```

Then use this:

```
$('#insertafter').after('<li><a href="http://test4.com">http://test4.com</a></li>');
```

There's also a `before` function :)